# Convert js Date().toISOString() to Python datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

The format of my csv file is this

```
Zeitstempel;Iteration;lag
"2022-01-26T22:28:11.347Z","1","2"
"2022-01-26T22:28:11.348Z","2","1"
```

and my python code is this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

csv_data = 'lag.log'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, encoding='latin1', sep=',', header=1,
names=['Zeitstempel', 'Iteration', 'Lag'])

df_cleaned = df.dropna()

x = df_cleaned['Zeitstempel'].values
y = df_cleaned['Lag'].values

#2022-01-26T21:59:30.810Z
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z").date() for date in x]

plt.plot_date(dates, y)
plt.show()
```

and the console output is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "chart.py", line 19, in <module>
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z").date() for date in x]
File "chart.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z").date() for date in x]
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2022-01-26T22:28:11.348Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.{0}Z'
```

Is there a way to convert the iso string to a datetime

Comment: I found the dateparser module very useful for date parsing. Has a generalized function for all (recognizable) formats. https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: #2022-01-26T21:59:30.810Z
dates = [dateparser.parse(date).date() for date in x] works great Thanks @csjh

Answer (score 2):

Python's `datetime.fromisoformat` does not accept the `'Z'` suffix, so you'll need to remove it.

```py
from datetime import datetime 


def datetime_from_js_isoformat(string: str) -> datetime:
    """Creates a datetime object from a JavaScript ISO format string."""

    if string.endswith('Z'):
        return datetime.fromisoformat(string[:-1])

    return datetime.fromisoformat(string)
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the more performant way. It works great Thanks